# How to fix Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:5001/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I am using ASP.NET Core 5 version `5.0.10` on .NET version `5.0.401` .
Error message

```
Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:5001/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'sha256-fa5rxHhZ799izGRP38+h4ud5QXNT0SFaFlh4eqDumBI='". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache: Application/Storage/"Clear Site Data" in dev tools

Comment: I tried this, the problem not change.

Comment: Can you share the script tag where you include it please? Also, are you 100% sure that sha string is correct?

Comment: I don't see it in source code, it generated by ASP.NET Core Blazor.

Comment: You can search this string in Google `sha256-fa5rxHhZ799izGRP38+h4ud5QXNT0SFaFlh4eqDumBI=`

Comment: I Create a sample using the same version: ASP.NET Core 5 version 5.0.10,  .NET version 5.0.401 and Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.3. The sample works well and doesn't meet the "Refused to load the script error". So, please check your VS 2019 version whether you are using the same version, and try to create a new Blazor WebAssembly application to check whether this issue exist or not? Besides, you can also try to downgrade asp.net core version and use the Asp.net Core 5.0.9 version and SDK 5.0.400 version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a hot reload issue. The problem is being tracked on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33068)